# How to enforce single threaded requests?

Tags: haproxy

I've started rate limiting my API using HAProxy, but my biggest problem is not so much the rate of requests, but when multi-threaded requests overlap.

Even within my legal per-second limits, big problems are occurring when clients don't wait for a response before issuing another request.

Is it possible (say, per IP address) to queue requests and pass them one at at time to the back end for sequential processing?

Comment: Then why not set limits on concurrent connections rather than requests rate. This way no matter how the clients behave, the number of established connections will be limited.

Comment: maxconn is already in effect. There's no problem with high number of connections across the board. I only need to limit overlapping requests by the same client.

Comment: I suppose "overlapping requests" here means http in keep-alive mode. If that is the case you can use [option httpclose](http://cbonte.github.io/haproxy-dconv/1.7/configuration.html#option%20httpclose), this should tell clients to send one request at a time.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, but clients doing parallel requests could still open a new connection for each thread, couldn't they? Seems it would just increase load if clients couldn't reuse connections.

Comment: I don't know what you mean exactly by "thread" here, there is no threads in HAProxy. So maybe you are talking about threads in the client side.  
Anyway yes the same source IP may do parallel requests, this is how things work for clients behind NAT and you application should support it.  
HAProxy can allow one request per src IP at a time, but parallel requests will be dropped and not queued.

Comment: I do mean client side, yes. Dropping subsequent parallel request may be acceptable to me. I'd accept your answer if you post how to achieve that.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a possible solution to enforce **one connection at a time per src IP**.
You need to put the following HAProxy conf in the corresponding frontend:

```
frontend fe_main
  mode http
  stick-table type ip size 1m store conn_cur
  tcp-request connection track-sc0 src
  tcp-request connection reject if { src_conn_cur gt 1 }
```

This will create a stick table that stores *concurrent connection counts* per source IP.  Then rejects new connections if there is already one established from the same src IP.

Browsers imitating multiple connections to your API or clients behind a NAT will not be able to efficiently use you API.